# Tag Wiki Editing - Copy from Wikipedia?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Is it acceptable for a user to copy and paste a load of information from Wikipedia into a tag wiki?

I have the opinion that it should be worded in the context of E&R, and give information about what type of questions are on/off topic for that particular tag.

Answer (score 3):

> I have the opinion that it should be worded in the context of E&R, and give information about what type of questions are on/off topic for that particular tag.

Indeed, you're absolutely right, this part is critically important.

I updated the sidebar editing help for the Tag Wikis to give better help on this. **Let me know if that help can be improved**; just bring up a tag wiki and check out the sidebar.

> Is it acceptable for a user to copy and paste a load of information from Wikipedia into a tag wiki?

It can be so long as it is properly attributed and linked back to Wikipedia (in the full wiki, since excerpts don't allow links). But as you said --

Comment: my understanding of US copyright law is that using enough of the information to remove the need to visit the original source is never fair use. Using a small amount and then referencing the source if they want more detail is fair use. Is this not the case?

Comment: scratch that, in the case of Wikipedia they have waived that right, in other sources it could be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

#### Similar questions on Meta Stack Overflow:

- [Would it be ok to paste content from wikipedia into a popular empty tag-wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79000/would-it-be-ok-to-paste-content-from-wikipedia-into-a-popular-empty-tag-wiki)
- [Copy and pasting wikipedia articles into tag-wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81047/copy-and-pasting-wikipedia-articles-into-tag-wikis)

MSO (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is for all intents and purposes "Meta Stack Exchange", but not yet called as such.