# Please help fix the Arduino tag wiki (and others)

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The [Arduino tag wiki](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/arduino/info) is a direct copy-paste of the text on http://www.arduino.cc/.

Because that text is ©Arduino, Arduino is one of the most-used tags, and the tag summary is far too verbose, would someone with more experience on Arduino than myself (never touched one in my life) mind suggesting a more original tag wiki which better follows the tag wiki guidelines:

> The tag wiki excerpt is a brief plain text introduction to the topic that the tag represents. It is shown at the top of tag question lists, and as a tooltip wherever the tag appears. Complete this first!
>
> The full tag wiki is a detailed introduction to the topic, suitable as a destination for those curious about it:
>
> ► what questions should have this tag?
>
> ► some basic definitions
>
> ► brief introduction to the subject
>
> ► important general links
>
> ► one reasonably sized page

Note that this should be done for all the tags, especially those on the first page or two.  [Copying information with attribution from another source](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/tag-wiki-editing-copy-from-wikipedia) is marginally acceptable for the brief introduction section of a tag wiki, but it is not sufficient.